# Produce integer (INT32) keys with Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I don't know if I'm off on a wild goose chase here, and trying to do something that's completely pointless, but I thought I'd ask anyway, as I've spent long enough hitting my head against a brick wall.

I'm pulling data into a Kafka topic from a database using Kafka connect. I want to use the `ID` field from the table as the message key, and have the following:

```
    transforms.valueToKey.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
    transforms.valueToKey.fields: ID
    transforms.extractId.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
    transforms.extractId.field: ID
```

This is working nicely to extract the ID from the data as they key; however, is it possible to then store that key as an integer?

I want to do this so that I can then use `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.Integer()` to deserialise the key in Kafka Streams.

I have tried:

```
key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

but then the stream complains `Size of data received by IntegerDeserializer is not 4`

I have tried:

```
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.JsonConvertor
    key.converter.schemas.enable: false
    key.converter.type.specific: INT32
```

Same error.

I have tried:

```
    key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
```

But then Kafka connect complains `Invalid schema type for ByteArrayConverter: INT32` (which suggests the data is in INT32 format - but how do I save it as such??).

I have tried:

```
    value.converter: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    value.converter.schema.registry.url: .....
```

And Kafka connect complains `Error registering Avro schema"int"`.

I have tried specifying no convertor, but it then seems to fall back to a default JSON convertor, and I can find no way to specify "don't use a convertor at all, just save the value in its current format".

I could just leave it as a String, and then convert it to an integer in the streams app, but the fact there is an `Integer` serdes suggests to me I should be able to have it as an integer to begin with, but maybe that's misleading.

Another option might be to write my own convertor, but it feels like such a standard thing to want to do that there should already be a way to do it - unless I am trying to do something silly/pointless/impossible/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID in the database table is INT32 try this:

**key.converter**: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter

**transforms.valueToKey.type**: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey

**transforms.valueToKey.fields**: ID

**transforms.valueToKey.field.schemas**: INT32  # Specify the schema for the ID field

**transforms.extractId.type**: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key

**transforms.extractId.field**: ID

If the ID in your database table is not an integer, but you want it to be represented as an integer in the Kafka topic, try this:

**transforms.valueToKey.type**: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey

**transforms.valueToKey.fields**: ID

**transforms.valueToKey.field.schemas**: INT32

**transforms.valueToKey.delimiter**: -

**transforms.valueToKey.key.field**: ID

**transforms.valueToKey.key.type**: int

Comment: Thank you. I was sure there must be an `IntegerConvertor`, but all my searching suggested there wasn't.

Comment: I initially just tried changing the class name at the end of `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`, but that failed (as it turns out, because the `IntegerConvertor` is in a different package!).

I tried googling and page after page just listed the Avro, ProtoBuf, Json, String and ByteArray convertors (though, it seems if only I had scrolled a little further down on [one page](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html), I would have seen it!).

Comment: And I tried ChatGPT, and it insisted there was none, and just kept suggesting methods using the Avro, Json, String and ByteArray convertors.

Now, of course, if I just copy and paste my above question into ChatGPT it suggests the `org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter`, even though I'd asked again and again, in so many ways, before, and it insisted that (to the best of its knowledge) there wasn't one.

Anyway, thank you, this has worked, and my sanity is (slightly, and momentarily) restored!

Comment: You are welcome !
Yes that happens a lot with ChatGPT